# What is wrong with my code? (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    public class MyProgram 
    { 
        Form Form1 = new Form();

        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {      
            Form1.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_Closing);
            Form1 .Show();        
        } 

        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
             e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

I got this error:

> Error Id: CS0120, Error: An object
>   reference is required for the
>   non-static field, method, or property
>   'MyProgram.Form1_Closing(object,
>   System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)',
>   Line: 10, Column: 30 Error Id: CS0120,
>   Error: An object reference is required
>   for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

Comment: the new Form() line would only be executed when you do a new MyProgram(). Looking at the code above.. you should move the Form() creation into the main method.

Comment: I just did, but still got an error: `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method or property 'MyProgram.Form1_Closing(object, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Form` instance variable cannot access your main class's `Form1_Closing()` callback because it's an instance method, but you're adding the event handler in a static context (your `Main()` method).

You have to either add that event handler using an instance of `MyProgram`, not through the `Main()` method:

```
MyProgram main = new MyProgram();
main.Form1.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(main.Form1_Closing);
main.Form1.Show();
```

Or declare your `Form` field a static field, and your `Form1_Closing()` event handler a static method so `Main()` can use them:

```
static Form Form1 = new Form();

private static void Form1_Closing(...)
```

Comment: change Form Form1 = new Form(); to static Form Form1 = new Form();

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `Form Form1 = new Form ()` in main.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to use a non-static property in a static context. Calling FormClosing from the static context of Main is what's giving you the problem.

Read more about it at [Microsoft's page for this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: so wht should be my solution?

Comment: @yonan2236 - What @SwDevMan81 said would work - put Form form1 = new Form() inside the main method.

Comment: still got his error: `Error Id: CS0120, Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyProgram.Form1_Closing(object, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)', Line: 10, Column: 30
Error Id: CS0120, Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `

Comment: You will need to make the method static as well

Answer (score 0):

As the error message points out, the `Form1` field and the `Form1_Closing` method are tied to *instances* of the `MyProgram` class, not to the *class itself*. You could make them static to fix the problem:

```
 static Form Form1 = new Form();

 static void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) { ... }
```

Alternatively, create an instance in the main method:

```
// really bad code; only a demonstration
var myProgram = new MyProgram();
myProgram.Form1.FormClosing += myProgram.Form1_Closing;
myProgram.Form1.Show();
```

Of course, there's no need for *any* of this since you don't appear to use the field anywhere else - you could just make it a local variable instead.

```
var form = new Form();
form.FormClosing += Form1_Closing; // make Form1_Closing a static method
form.Show();
```

You could also choose to write the trivial event-handler method as a lambda instead:

```
form.FormClosing += (sender, e) => e.Cancel = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that because you're attempting to access a member variable from a static function, the member variable itself needs to be static.

Answer (score -1):

You have several problems here. The main one is that you are trying to show a Form inside a console application and that is bound to fail. To have a user interface you need a user interface thread that is processing windows messages. I recommend that you use the Visual Studio templates to create a new blank WinForms application that will show you the way to create a starting Form that shows.